# sed substitution while reading a file happens in unexpected lines

Tags: bash, macos, unix, sed, markdown

I'm on macOS 11.0.1. I'm writing a bash script which processes markdown files. It has to read a file line by line (except for a $HEADER variable at the beginning) and:

- Do not edit lines starting with #
- Add a prefix (`{{< p "`) and a suffix (`" >}}`) to all the other lines

This is what I got so far:

```
while read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" == \#* ]]; then
        echo $line >> $OUTPUT
        continue
    else
        sed -E 's/^/{{< p "/; s/$/" >}}/' >> $OUTPUT
    fi
done < <(tail -n "+$HEADER" $INPUT)
```

This is my input (with no header):

```
## I

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
```

I expect that the first line is ignored, but this the output:

```
{{< p "## I" >}}

{{< p "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text" >}}
```

Weird thing is that the "if" works without sed, because I can forward the matched lines on another file... if sed line is commented out.
What am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't supply any input to `sed`, so it's going to ignore `$line` and instead read the rest of the file from stdin (i.e. from the `tail` command). Also, you should double-quote variables like `$line` when you use them (i.e. `echo "$line"` instead of `echo $line`).

But it looks to me like you could replace the entire loop with a single `sed` command:

```
tail -n "+$HEADER" "$INPUT" | sed '/^#/ ! s/^.*$/{{< p & >}}/' >"$$OUTPUT"
```

Explanation: the `/^#/ !` prefix tells `sed` to apply this only to lines that *don't* start with "#". Then the `s/^.*$/{{< p & >}}/` command replaces the entire line with "{{< p ", followed by `&` which tells `sed` to insert the entire match (the original line), followed by " >}}".

Comment: Thanks! The `tail` command is perfect, but I wanted to keep the loop because I could add some more characters/regex to avoid in the `if` statement. Is there a way to perform multiple checks on sed (eg. if the first character is "#" or "-")?

Comment: I answer to myself: I could just insert them in square brackets e.g.: `sed '/^[#-]/ ! s/^.*$/{{< p & >}}/' >"$OUTPUT"`